# How to edit value in CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am beginning to learn python and I have this project where I have a menu that either adds, lists, or updates values for books in a csv. The headers are "BookName", "AuthorName", "SharedWith", "IsRead" and I am trying to change the "IsRead" row for a given book added by the user.
My problem is that whenever I am trying to edit the row that contains that book, I end up deleting all other rows instead. All I want to do is to update a value for a certain row in a csv. Here's the function that I wrote.

```
def updateBook():
book_name = input("Enter book name: ")
import csv
rows_list = []
with open('booksDB.csv', mode='r') as file:
    rows = list(csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=("BookName", "AuthorName", "SharedWith", "IsRead")))
    for row in rows:
        rows_list.append(row["BookName"]) # we store every book name in a list
    if book_name not in rows_list: # we search the book the user typed in our list
        add_new_book = input(f' The {book_name} book does not exits. Would you like to add it? (Y/N)? ')
        if add_new_book.upper() == "N":
            return
        else:
            addBook()
            return
    else:
        book_read = input("Is the book read? (Y/N)? ")
        if book_read.upper() == 'Y':
            book_read = True
        else:
            book_read = False
        rows = []
with open('booksDB.csv', mode='r') as file:
    rows = list(csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=("BookName", "AuthorName", "SharedWith", "IsRead")))
    for row in rows:
        if row["BookName"] == book_name:
            row["IsRead"] = book_read
            break
with open('booksDB.csv',mode='r+') as file:  # WIP, here I can't make the csv keep all books in the list when editing a certain one
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=[
        "BookName", "AuthorName", "SharedWith", "IsRead"
    ])
    if row["IsRead"] == book_read:
        csv_writer.writerow({"BookName": row.get("BookName"),
                             "AuthorName": row.get("AuthorName"),
                             "SharedWith": row.get("SharedWith"),
                             "IsRead": book_read})
    print("Book was updated successfully")
```

Comment: i didn't read all that, but it doesn't look like you open any files in 'w' mode. There is extensive documentation on the csv library online, give it a look

Comment: SUGGESTION: 1) Read the file just as you're doing now.  2) Ensure that "rows" exists *outside of* (independent of) any of your csv read/write blocks.  3) Change/add/delete rows as needed.  4) When you're done, open ' booksDB.csv' for "write".  You *DON'T* need "r+"; you *DON'T* need a second "read" block.  5) Use a csv Writer (you *don't* need a DictWriter).  Simply call `writerows()`.  Done.  Easy peasy :)

Answer (score 0):

The First Thing You Should Open Your CSV File In a 'w' Mode Not 'r'

After I Looked at your Code You Didn't Respect The Indentation For your Function Try To Fix it First

Did You Try To Give Input First

```
roww = input("Enter The Name Of The Row Here : ")
```

and After use it :

```
for row in rows:
    if row["BookName"] == book_name:
        row[rf"{roww}"] = book_read
        break
```

Try This it Might Help

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your support. I made a small tweak and managed to get the code working 100% with the following lines:

```
def updateBook():
    book_name = input("Enter book name: ")
    import csv
    rows = []
    rows_list = []
    with open('booksDB.csv', mode='r') as file:
        rows = list(csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=("BookName", "AuthorName", "SharedWith", "IsRead")))
        for row in rows:
            rows_list.append(row["BookName"])  # we store every book name in a list
        if book_name not in rows_list:  # we search the book the user typed in our list
            add_new_book = input(f' The {book_name} book does not exits. Would you like to add it? (Y/N)? ')
            if add_new_book.upper() == "N":
                return
            else:
                addBook()
                return
        else:
            book_read = input("Is the book read? (Y/N)? ")
            if book_read.upper() == 'Y':
                book_read = True
            else:
                book_read = False
            rows = []
    with open('booksDB.csv', mode='r') as file:
        rows = list(csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=("BookName", "AuthorName", "SharedWith", "IsRead")))
        for row in rows:
            if row["BookName"] == book_name:
                row["IsRead"] = book_read
                break
    with open('booksDB.csv',mode='w') as file:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=["BookName", "AuthorName", "SharedWith", "IsRead"])
        csv_writer.writerows(rows)
    print("Book was updated successfully!")
```